# how to find the shortest distance between two regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a set of documents, where I can search for specific entities, and I need to find the shortest distance between two.
Let's say I have a document where I search for `Trump` and `Ukraine`, and I get the list of mentions, with their start and end positions:

```
import re

text = """
 Three constitutional scholars invited by Democrats to testify at Wednesday’s impeachment hearings said that President Trump’s efforts to pressure Ukraine for political gain clearly meet the historical definition of impeachable offenses, according to copies of their opening statements.
 ˜Noah Feldman, a professor at Harvard, argued that attempts by Mr. Trump to withhold a White House meeting and military assistance from Ukraine as leverage for political favors constitute impeachable conduct, as does the act of soliciting foreign assistance on a phone call with Ukraine’s leader.
"""
p1 = re.compile("Trump")
p2 = re.compile("Ukraine")
res1 = [{'name':m.group(), 'start': m.start(), "end":m.end()} for m in p1.finditer(text)]
res2 = [{'name':m.group(), 'start': m.start(), "end":m.end()} for m in p2.finditer(text)]
print(res1)
print(res2)
```

output:

```
[{'name': 'Trump', 'start': 120, 'end': 125}, {'name': 'Trump', 'start': 356, 'end': 361}]
[{'name': 'Ukraine', 'start': 148, 'end': 155}, {'name': 'Ukraine', 'start': 425, 'end': 432}, {'name': 'Ukraine', 'start': 568, 'end': 575}]
```

In this specific case the answer is `148 - 125 = 23`. How would you recommend to do it in the most pythonic way?

Comment: *most pythonic way* is quite opinion-based.

Comment: @ctwheels I totally agree. On the other hand, if a person has an opinion about the _most pythonic_ way, then s/he can share it. If not, it doesn't exist for this specific individual :)

Comment: @chepner well, I added this just for having reproducible example

Comment: Retracted the comment; looking at Prince Francis's answer, you could argue that this is an XY problem and `res1` and `res2` aren't necessary at all.

Comment: What is the significance of finding the distance between 2 words ?

Comment: @x15 it is used in media studies. For instance here: https://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/ICWSM/ICWSM10/paper/view/1441/1852 they use joint mentions of two parties in Twitter as a predictor of a potential coalition between these two parties.

Comment: No, I don't believe this is a valid test of a coalition between parties. It's all about context and subject matter and within a given fixed frame of reference. Without that it's meaningless. With that, it's impossible to calculate frames of reference. Take your pick. And what about this `A.....B..A......B` ? So, I can't buy that, it's all psycho junk talk / theory to me .

Comment: well, it is not the *test*, it can be served as a predictor of a *future* coalition - and it is clearly testable theory: you either can predict the coalition based on the data or not. But you are right in a sense that it should be combined with a sentiment analysis to get the context.

Comment: Use formal symbolic logic analysis, create an equation from the text, solve the equation, then filter out errors. By the time you're done there won't be any written text to base a testable theory on.

Answer (score 2):

one solutions is to extract the match and find it's length as below

```
min([len(x) for x in re.findall(r'Trump(.*?)Ukraine', text)])
```

Here it prints 23

Comment: This may not work for larger distances. Especially with line breaks this will go awry.

Answer (score 2):

Use `itertools.product`:

```
min(x['start'] - y['end'] for x, y in product(res2, res1) if x['start'] - y['end'] > 0)
```

Or with latest Python 3.8+ leveraging the ***walrus*** operator, I guess you can also do (untested):

```
min(res for x, y in product(res2, res1) if res := x['start'] - y['end'] > 0)
```

**Code**:

```
from itertools import product

res1 = [{'name': 'Trump', 'start': 120, 'end': 125}, {'name': 'Trump', 'start': 356, 'end': 361}]
res2 =[{'name': 'Ukraine', 'start': 148, 'end': 155}, {'name': 'Ukraine', 'start': 425, 'end': 432}, {'name': 'Ukraine', 'start': 568, 'end': 575}]

print(min(x['start'] - y['end'] for x, y in product(res2, res1) if x['start'] - y['end'] > 0))
# 23
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to take the absolute value of the distance between two points, otherwise the shortest distance will become negative, which is I assume not what you want:

```
dict = [{'name': 'Trump', 'start': 120, 'end': 125}, {'name': 'Trump', 'start': 356, 'end': 361}, {'name': 'Ukraine', 'start': 148, 'end': 155}, {'name': 'Ukraine', 'start': 425, 'end': 432}, {'name': 'Ukraine', 'start': 568, 'end': 575}]

shortest = 99999999
start = -1
end = -1

for i in range(len(dict)):
    for j in range(len(dict)):
        if(i != j):
            dist = abs(dict[i]['start'] - dict[j]['end'])
            if(dist < shortest):
                shortest = dist
                start = i
                end = j

print("Start: {}, end: {}, distance: {}\n".format(dict[start]['name'], dict[end]['name'], shortest))
```

Comment: You could get around this by using the sorted builtin to sort your list by the "start" key. like: `sorted(dict, key=lambda x: x["start"])`.